# Pythonic way to to loop through object attributes and assign new attribute

Tags: python, oop

I am working with a large object `a` in Python. The object has two other iterable objects `b` and `c` passed to it as attributes `one` and `two`.

I want to consolidate the important data in the object prior to passing it to the templating engine. I am trying to take an attribute from `one` and assign it to `two`.

My first thought was to parse the two objects with two stacked `for` loops like this..

```py
for c in a.two:
    for a in a.one:
        if a.id == c.id:
            setattr(c, 'title', a.title)
```

However, I am not sure if this is the most pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: It could be converted to a list comprehension which would probably be a little bit faster. I'm not sure how else it could be improved, but I imagine somebody on here would know how to implement `itertools` or something to reduce the time complexity of it!

Comment: Be careful comparing `ids` as they will sometimes act in unexpected manners especially on multi threaded programs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can improve your code from a time complexity of *O(n x m)* to *O(n + m)* (quadratic to linear) by building a dict for each list that maps the `id`s of objects in the list to the objects, and using set intersection between the dict keys to find the common `id`s between the two lists instead. Also, you don't need to use the `setattr` function if the attribute name you're setting is fixed; you can assign to the object's attribute directly instead:

```
one = {obj.id: obj for obj in a.one}
two = {obj.id: obj for obj in a.two}
for id in set(one).intersection(two):
    two[id].title = one[id].title
```